# Issue when filtering rows of numpy array by multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy, filtering, conditional-statements

I want to filter a numpy array by multiple conditions. I found 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501823/numpy-filtering-rows-by-multiple-conditions)  and tested the slicing method on my dataset but I get unexpected results. Well, at least for me they're unexpected, as I might simply have a problem understanding the functionality of bitwise operators or something else :/

Just so you get an idea of the data:

```
test.shape
>>(222988, 2)

stats.describe(all_output[:, 0])
>>DescribeResult(nobs=222988, minmax=(2.594e-05, 74.821), mean=11.106, variance=108.246, [...])

stats.describe(all_output[:, 1])
>>DescribeResult(nobs=222988, minmax=(0.001, 8.999), mean=3.484, variance=7.606, [...])
```

Now, doing some basic filtering:

```
test1 = test[(test[:, 0] >= 30) & (test[:, 1] <= 2)] 

test1.shape
>>(337, 2)
```

Those are actually the rows I **don't** want to have in my dataset, so if I do what I believe is the opposite...

```
test2 = test[(test[:, 0] <= 30) & (test[:, 1] >= 2)] 

test2.shape
>>(112349, 2)
```

I would expect the result to be (222651, 2). I guess that I'm doing some embarrassingly simple thing wrong? Can anyone here push me in the right direction?

Thanks already! -M

Comment: The opposite of A and B is notA _or_ notB and the opposite of >= is <. I.e.: `test2 = test[(test[:, 0] < 30) | (test[:, 1] > 2)]` should do the Job.

Comment: That makes it clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[De morgans law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `not (p and q) == (not p) *or* (not q)`. Anyway, the not operator in [numpy is `~`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728708/inverting-a-numpy-boolean-array-using) so

```
 ~((test[:, 0] >= 30) & (test[:, 1] <= 2)) == ((test[:, 0] < 30) | (test[:, 1] > 2))
```

Either will do what you want, e.g.

```
test1 = test[~((test[:, 0] >= 30) & (test[:, 1] <= 2))]
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I feel really stupid, because I even used  ~ in my code before. But thanks for giving me some context about De morgans law!